# Vue equivalent of {{content?.body}} interpolation

Tags: javascript, angular, vue.js

In angular we could do something like `{{content?.body}}` and it will render the content body if it exist in your data.

This doesn't seem to work in Vue. Is there a way to achieve this or i have to check manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Vue you can use **v-if** directive. For example;

```
 <div v-if="content.body">
   {{content.body}}
 </div>
```

See for more at [Vue official docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

Comment: Yeah i ended up using v-if. I was hoping there was a simpler syntax

Answer (score 0):

This syntax does not exist in vue.js and it will probably never exists according to the creator of Vue.js ([see this post](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4638))

However you could use [get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get) from lodash combined with computed property to simulate this behavior :

```
computed: {
   nestedProperty() {
     return get(this, 'here.is.my.nested.property')
   }
}
```

But the easiest way is probably to just add `v-if` directive to your template to check that property exists

Comment: Yeah i ended up using v-if.

Answer (score 0):

I’m guessing you’re looking for a similar approach to optional unwrap from swift or safe call operator from kotlin.
Neither JS or Vue.js support this.

Your safest bet is to use a v-if on the entire chain

```
<span v-if=“content && content.body”>
  {{content.body}}
</span>
```